# ssh to VM through bastion with key

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I am trying to SSH to EC2 through bastion(jump-box), but had an issue with it. I tried it with `.ssh/config` and it worked. But I want to do it as a command NOT with `.ssh/config` (I know its the correct way)

local-host ---> bastion ---> ec2

ubuntu user present on bastion & ec2, key (dev-key.pem) present on local-host only.

I tried bunch of solution along with this :

```
local-host$ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ubuntu/automator/dev-key.pem -A -t ubuntu@${bastion} -A -t ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o -i /home/ubuntu/automator/dev-key.pem StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${ec2} "hostname > /tmp/hostname.txt"
```

error :

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Anybody can help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/command/) you can use the `ssh -J` option:

> -J [user@]host[:port] Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the pjump host[(/iam/jump-host) and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.

So your command will be:

```
local-host$ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ubuntu/automator/dev-key.pem -J ubuntu@${bastion} ubuntu@${ec2} "hostname > /tmp/hostname.txt"
```

Comment: I am on `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`, and dont see `-J` flag. Seams its for newer version.